# Show latest used taxonomy in homepage

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Im not sure if my title its the correct, i need to make something in homepage to show recent custom-taxonomies used in my latest posts... like, for example:

I make a new post and i use a custom taxonomy called Actors: Juan

i want to show "Juan" taxonomy in the homepage, below a title that say "Recent actors" or something like that

I was thinking about a tag cloud but i dont know if i can change tags by custom taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'        => 'post_type_name', // or use default if you use standard
    'numberposts'      => 3,  // or you can use 1 if you need only from last post.
    'orderby'          => 'date', //by dates to get lastest
    'order'            => 'DESC',
);

$posts = get_posts($args);
$recent_taxonomies = [];
foreach ($posts as $key => $post_data) {
    $recent_taxonomies[] = get_the_terms( $post_data->ID, 'custom_taxonomy_name'); 
}
```

More about `get_posts` https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts
More about `get_the_terms` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

If you want create cloud tag from this you can base on returned objects and `count` for each object, then based on it create cloud.

For simply tag cloud you could use (where `$name` is a taxonomy name)
(it create cloud from whole taxonomy)

```
function tagsCloudByTerm($name){
    $tags_out = null;
    $tax_terms = get_terms($name);
    $tags_out = '<span class="tag-meta ">';
    $tmp = [];
    $max = 0;
    if(!empty($tax_terms)):
        foreach ($tax_terms as $term) :
            if($max < $term->count){
                $max = $term->count;
            }
        endforeach;
        foreach ($tax_terms as $term) :
             $percent = floor(($term->count / $max) * 100);
             if ($percent < 20):
               $class = 'smallest';
             elseif ($percent >= 20 and $percent < 40):
               $class = 'small';
             elseif ($percent >= 40 and $percent < 60):
               $class = 'medium';
             elseif ($percent >= 60 and $percent < 80):
               $class = 'large';
             else:
             $class = 'largest';
             endif;
            $term_link_url = get_term_link($term, $post_taxonomies[$tag_key]);
            $tmp[] = '<a class="'.$class.'" href="'.$term_link_url.'" title="'.$term->name.'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
        endforeach;
    endif;
    $tags_out .= implode(', ', $tmp);
    unset($tmp);
    $tags_out = $tags_out.'</span>';
    return $tags_out ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
 add_shortcode('get_latest_taxonomy', 'get_latest_taxonomy');
        function get_latest_taxonomy()
        {
            global $wpdb;
            $args = array('post_type'=>'POST_TYPE_NAME','posts_per_page'=>-1);
            $result =  get_posts($args);
            $cat_name = array();
            foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                $ids = $value->ID;
                $cate = get_the_terms($ids, 'YOUR_TAXONOMY_NAME');
                foreach ($cate as $k => $v) {
                    $cat_name[] = $v->name;
                }
            }
            $latest_cate = array_unique($cat_name);
            echo "<ul>";
            foreach ($latest_cate as $latest_cate_key => $latest_cate_value) {
                echo "<li>";
                print_r($latest_cate_value);
                echo "</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
        }
```